# javascript regular expression optional character

Tags: javascript, regex, option-type

I want to replace url parameters by using regular expression.

My code :

```
query = window.location.search;
query.replace(new RegExp(query.match('f=(.*)&?')[1],'g'),'2');
```

But there is possible two situation,

first:

query can be "?f=23"

second:

query can be "?f=23&id=1",

my code work for first situation , but it doesn't work for second situation.

How can I replace my query for both situation ?

---

```
function control(parameter,value) {

var newUrl;
var url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
var query = window.location.search;
var check = query.indexOf('f');

if (check == -1) {

    var qCheck = query.indexOf('?');
    if (qCheck == -1) {
        query = query+'?'+parameter+'='+value;
    } else {
        query = query+'&'+parameter+'='+value;
    }

} else {

    var c = query.indexOf('&');
    if(c == -1) {
        query = query.replace(new RegExp(query.match(parameter+'=(.*)')[1],'g'),value);

    } else {

        query = query.replace(new RegExp(query.match('f=(.*)&')[1],'g'),value);
    }

}   

    history.pushState(null,null,url+query); 
}
```

Comment: That code looks much more complicated than it needs to be...

Comment: Do you want to replace all of the query parameters with '2'?

Comment: no , I want to replace just the parameter f with value 2 ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
/(f=)([^\s|&]+)/g
```

Usage in JavaScript

```
'?f=23'.replace(/(f=)([^\s|&]+)?/g, '$12');
'?f=23&id=1'.replace(/(f=)([^\s|&]+)?/g, '$12');
'?a=22&f=24'.replace(/(f=)([^\s|&]+)?/g, '$12');
```

Output:

```
?f=2
?f=2&id=1
?a=22&f=2
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xP9zY3/1)

Comment: it is work , but when my query is '?a=22&f=24' or something like that , my code doesn't work , I added all my code, you can see my all code from my question. thank you

Comment: @sanchez23 Even on this sequence `?a=22&f=24` the pattern above will match and replace `f=24` to `f=2`. Check the updated answer, chack the demo and in the meantime I'll check your code.

Comment: I check my code , it is work perfectly :) thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to replace the parameter `f` with the value 2, therefore:

```
query = window.location.search;
query = query.replace( /f=(.*?)&?/g, 'f=2' );
```

the `.*?` makes the match non-greedy.

Comment: yes, I want to replace the parameter f with value 2, but your code don't make it. your code make "?f=2" to "?2"

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```
query = window.location.search; // "?f=23&id=1"
query.replace( /(f=).*(&)/, '$1'+ '2' +'$2' );

> "?f=2&id=1"

query.replace( /(f=).*(&)/, '$1'+ 'something' +'$2' );

> "?f=something&id=1"
```

Comment: What do you mean? My code works I tested it... are you sure? Give me your full query string so I can see what's wrong.

Comment: I added all my code in my question , i want to make a function that is replace parameter from query